# Logstash - add new field by multi condition

Tags: logstash

Good afternoon. Logs from network devices are transferred to Logstash using syslog.

```
  beats {
        type => "filebeat_nginx_proxy_connect"
        port => 5044
  }
  syslog {
        type => "syslog"
        port => 5145
        host => "0.0.0.0"
 }
}
```

Then they get into elastic and are displayed in kibana
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

As you can see from the picture, the ip address of the device is displayed. I have a mapping of ip addresses of all devices and their sysname. How can I add a new field (for example, sysname) to the document that will display the device name. I tried using mutate (add_fields) and if conditions, but a lot of conditions are obtained since the number of devices is about 2500 thousand. Maybe I need to write my own filter for logstash. But I don't know how and where to look for information. Please help..

I tried using mutate (add_fields) and if conditions, but a lot of conditions are obtained since the number of devices is about 2500 thousand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a mapping of the IP addresses of all devices and their sysname, you could simply leverage the [`translate` filter plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-translate.html) which does exactly that, i.e. map the value of one field into another value stored in another field:

```
translate {
    source => "[ip_field]"
    target => "[sysname_field]"
    override => true
    dictionary_path => "/path/to/ip/file/mapping.csv"
    fallback => "N/A"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This is what was needed. Already configured and tested. Everything is working!!